# How to Add several categories/taxonomies of search in EEA Faceted Navigation of Plone?

Tags: plone

I am new in plone and content management tools.
we have an installed plone where our lab's publication list locates. 
i simply want something like the demos of eea navigation, where i can define e.g. a widget for authors a widget for venues, and a widget for year of our publication lists.

I have installed eea facted navigation on plone. 
it allows me to have e.g. a checkbox widget on my defined tags (those that i define in the categorization tab of the pages or files).
but now all tags (authors, years, venues, etc.) appear in all widgets which use "tag".
How can i put constraint on the widget in eea faceted navigation.
or alternatively
how can i define my own categories more tag-types
or even other vocabularies
I am not sure what is the easiest possible way to solve it.

any help?
HH.

Answer (score 3):

There is one thing you can do to manually create vocabularies to do:

Install Products.ATVocabularyManager. With this product, you can create vocabularies TTW and I believe faceted nav can pull these in(it says it can in the documentation).

What you're seeing on the demos is likely a custom content type with a custom index setup. So it's not likely in the demos that they had put all that data into tags--they were different fields on their content that was indexed by the catalog. This way is a lot nicer to work with and you could look into plone.app.dexterity if you want to go this route.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make my own vocabulary with Products.ATVocabularyManager and EEA.faceted Nav worked with that